# Cant put Header and Navigation bar next to each other

Tags: html, css

Im making my first website so this question is maybe a kind of noobie ^^.
I want my header (image) and navigation bar next to each other.
But it won't work

Screen:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjReh.png]

And when we fixed that, i want the navigation bar to be as big as the header. So it fits great!

Can someone help me with this?
I couldn't paste the code somehow so here is a jsfiddle

Codes:
http://jsfiddle.net/pu5uT/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: could you post a jsfiddle with only the code for that part of the site, as it is confusing to look at that much code and find the issue.  Also, your css is formatted in a really hard to read way!

Comment: Hi Sam, here is a jsfiddle with only the problem http://jsfiddle.net/pu5uT/3/    .  But it's to hard for me to make my css readable :P

Comment: one thing, you have linked your style sheet in the body, try putting the link in the head, although it does not make a big difference in this case

Comment: I did that. But nothing changed.

Comment: Yea, that would not change anything on your page, but its how its supposed to be done so thought I would mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this as your css for #nav

```
#nav {
position:relative;
background:#000000;
text-align:center;
width:75%;
left:25%;
top:0px;
margin-top:-34px;   }
```

this works for me, hope this helps :)

EDIT:(I just changed it slightly as realised a better solution)

And for the height issue:

```
#headerbg {
position:relative;
background:#000000;
text-align:center;
width:25%;
height:209px;
margin-top:-8px;
}
#nav {
position:relative;
background:#000000;
text-align:center;
float:right;
width:75%;
top:0px;
margin-top:-240px;
height:240px;
}
```

this should work, but you may need to change some of the values as divs tend to be slightly bigger than the images they contain.

Comment: That worked for me! Ty! But now I got one more problem. I want the black part of the header to be as big as the black part of the navigation bar. But now it aint. Can you help me with that? Now i got this. http://jsfiddle.net/pu5uT/6/ . This is the link to my website so you can see the picture ^^: http://atweekend.mathildenijssen.nl/index3.html

Comment: what is the height of your image, as it does not load into fiddle

Comment: The height of my image is: 209px

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm having a hard time reading your code but your end result that you want for your navigation bar seems very similar to what I have for a website I'm working on, so you're welcome to use/borrow parts from it. http://jsfiddle.net/qx2YX/

http://jsfiddle.net/qx2YX/embedded/result/

HTML:

```
<!--LOGO AND NAVIGATION BAR-->
<header id="logoandnav">
<div id="mainlogodiv">
    <img id="mainlogo" src="images/logo.png" alt="" />
</div>
<nav>
    <ul class="navlist">
        <li><a class="navigation" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="navigation" href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a class="navigation" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a class="navigation" href="sponsors.html">Sponsors</a></li>
        <li><a class="navigation" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    width: 940px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: #e8eae9;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    margin: auto;
}
::selection {
    background: #8ec63f; /* Safari */
}
::-moz-selection {
    background: #8ec63f; /* Firefox */
}

#logoandnav {
    background-color: #0b0f0c;
    height: 112px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    line-height: 112px;
}
#logoandnav:before {
    width: 100%;
    height: inherit;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    content:"";
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: inherit;
}

/* MAIN LOGO */
 #mainlogodiv {
    float: left;
    line-height: 112px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#mainlogo {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/* NAVIGATION MENU */
 nav {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 112px;
    line-height: 112px;
}
ul.navlist li {
    height: 112px;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul.navlist {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
a.navigation:link, a.navigation:visited {
    font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    color: #e2e2e2;
    padding: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 112px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
a.navigation:hover, a.navigation:active {
    color: #0b0f0c;
    background-color: #8ec63f;
}
```

I would have added this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.